# mariadb 10.3 not sending CA certificate, so clients can't verify the server

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb

I've partially successfully installed a Let's Encrypt certificate for mariadb 10.3.34
I've configured a user with REQUIRE SSL and that works fine with local command line.
Server system is Ubuntu 20.04.1

```
| ssl_ca              | /etc/getssl/myserver/chain.crt                       |
| ssl_capath          |                                                                         |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/getssl/myserver/myserver.crt |
| ssl_cipher          |                                                                         |
| ssl_crl             |                                                                         |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                                                         |
| ssl_key             | /etc/getssl/myserver/myserver.key |
```

Remote command line from Ubuntu 22.x results in:

`ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Using `openssl s_client -starttls mysql -connect myserver:3306` shows the server certificate, with the correct CN=

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = myserver
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: DH, 2048 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2794 bytes and written 376 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
```

but there is no chain certificate sent by the server so the server certificate can't be verified.
I could install the chain certificate locally, but I thought it was meant to be supplied.

This server is supposed to support several clients, so I would rather a server-based solution if possible.

I've Googled around and tried various things for the last couple of hours, and even asked Google Bard for suggestions.  Bard suggested the same things as the other posts I read.

Comment: While that question is pretty old I couldn't find any indication that this behavior has changed since.

Comment: I'd have thought `ssl_cert` should hold the chain, while `ssl_ca` is the trust-anchor for verifying client certificates.

Comment: I tried `ssl_cert=fullchain.crt` with no change. Looks like I'll have to use a completely different approach.